# Database backup in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Due to the limited execution time and memory available to PHP, backing up very large databases may not be possible** -- This line is from CI's dbutil class doc. In which I understand it saying:

```
//php has a timeout of execution which is short also when it attempts to
// execute a time consuming action like db-backup might time out before
// completion..(Please mark If I were wrong)
```

And.. **Limited Memory** is php runtime memory that is found in the **php.ini** file which is 2048 by default.

Well with these lines I'm pretty sure it's gonna bring a issue when I'm going to backup a large database. What can I do instead?

```
 //1. Stored proceedure with event?
 // Well I want it to be executed once a day(so the event thing came up) or
 //2. Increase memory in php.ini?
```

**Which way should I go between these and others out there..?**

Comment: why back up a db from within PHP? That's why there's mysqldump, which has nothing at all to do with php.

Comment: This needs more context. What kind of a server are you on? Your own, or shared hosting? Do you have command line access to it?

Comment: Yeah personally I run a mysqldump on a cron job everynight that emails me the backup of the DB

Comment: @Chitowns24 Do u mean I should go with like first option I put above?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm on localhost so far.. So I have each and every privileges.

Comment: You could use `mysqldump` then and bypass PHP entirely.

Comment: I run my cron job off of a PHP file outside of my CI installation and it runs a command line mysqldump (it also does other things why its a PHP file)

Comment: @MarcB I dont really want to do it from php but I have to let the application user to have easy access on this.. And for better data security and reliability I need to keep at least 5 consecutive backups so that If needed any of them could be restored. It should be like a cron job.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah I'm going to do that..

Comment: @Chitowns24 Well I think in or out doesn't matter. BTW could u put the line here..the mysqldump from the shell which u actually wrote in your php file?

Comment: $command = "mysqldump -u $dbuser --password=$dbpwd $dbname | gzip > $filename";
$result = passthru($command);

Obviously you have to fill out the variables

Comment: @Pekka웃 do u know how to use mysqldump inside an script in a stored procedure or anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a backup utility such as [MySQLDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/) as it uses another technique to avoid PHP maximum execution time. Here's a quote from the official site:

> **MySQLDumper**
>
> A PHP script has a maximum execution time that is usually set to 30
> seconds on most server installations. A script running longer than
> this limit will simply stop working. This behavior makes backing up
> large databases impossible. Maybe you already had this specific
> problem when using other tools.
>
> MySQLDumper uses a proprietary technique to avoid this problem. It
> only reads and saves a certain amount of data, then calls itself
> recursively via JavaScript and remembers how far in the backup process
> it was. The script then resumes backing up from that point.

Comment: I think you have got the main issue here.. But is that some third party utility? Well did u use that?

Comment: Yes, it's a third party utility (and it's free). I've been using this (since 2010) to back up databases greater than 2GB without any performance issues. What I really like with this script is, you can see the database back up progress and you can even control the speed at which the database should be backed up!